# How to start an application on the server from a webpage

Tags: apache, debian

Example:

The user login to the webpage => Click on a button 
This action starts the executable "CreatePrettyPicture" 
The file "prettypicture.jpg" is created on the server
When the user reloads the page the pretty picture "PrettyPicture.jpg" is shown on the page.

If I could start the application with a parameter it would be even better.

The server is a using Debian and as web server I'm using Apache. Please let me know if you need more information about the server configuration.

The possibility of several users clicking on the button at the same time is not a part of the problem.

Comment: We definitely need to know what language you are using.

Comment: If it´s possible I would prefer to solve it with java.
But i have full controll over the server so feel free to come with suggestions.

Comment: Then you could perhaps try jsp with apache tomcat.

Comment: should i use tomcat INSTEAD of apache or are they supposed to run "together"?

Comment: Apache tomcat is run as a separate process or instead of apache afaik, and only one can listen to the port 80 afaik. IMO PHP sounds easier. :p

Comment: don't use PHP unless you really know what you're doing or _someone_else_ will get full control over the server

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would be better of using a server side script with your apache installation to start the executable. This is probably easier with PHP (which should be easy to install if it isnt already), [here are the commands](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.exec.php). As long as you dont actually use any input with the page it should be safe enough.

Answer (score 2):

You need to read up on [CGI Scripts](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_Gateway_Interface).

It's also possible that PHP is already available on your server, but I wouldn't recommend using it unless you're already familiar with it and know all of the security pitfalls, which from the question appears very unlikely.